# How to get SQL Server login audit setting using T-SQL or sys view

Tags: sql-server, properties, authentication, audit

In SSMS > Server Properties > Secuirty page, I can view/change the "Login Auditing" to "None, Failed Only, Successful Only..." 
Is there a way though to get the property value using TSQL/system catalog/view/DMV? I would like to incorperate that into a script to generate a report.

Thanks

Comment: In addition to Tim's answer, and depending on your MSSQL version, if you want a documented way to get the audit level, you can [use SMO](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.server.auditlevel.aspx). This would mean writing a CLR function or procedure if you want to do it in a SQL script, so it may be too much trouble for you.

Answer (score 5):

This info is actually stored in the registry, so AFAIK you'll need to use an undocumented proc to grab it:

```
declare @AuditLevel int
exec master..xp_instance_regread 
    @rootkey='HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE',
    @key='SOFTWARE\Microsoft\MSSQLServer\MSSQLServer',
    @value_name='AuditLevel',
    @value=@AuditLevel output
select @AuditLevel
```

Here's the key to the return values:
None = 0
Successful Logins Only = 1
Failed Logins Only = 2
Both Failed and Successful Logins = 3

I credit [Tim Radney](http://timradney.com/2012/01/03/sql-server-login-auditing/) and [SSC's Jason L](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic698590-146-2.aspx#bm1271346) for this info.

Answer (score 1):

you need the name of the instance in the path it the SQL is installed as a name instance instead of default instance.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use

```
execute xp_loginconfig 'audit level';
```

This seems to be Microsoft's preferred method, but since it is a stored procedure, using the output in another query has all the usual headaches of getting data from a stored procedure.